# Having trouble updating my firmware "Error processing Archive"

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, system-installation, upgrade, firmware

On Ubuntu OS

sudo apt-get upgrade

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-firmware
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/24.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 322 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 294300 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-firmware_1.143.6_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-firmware (1.143.6) over (1.143.3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.143.6_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create `/lib/firmware/brcm/bcm4329-fullmac-4.bin.dpkg-new' (while processing `./lib/firmware/brcm/bcm4329-fullmac-4.bin'): Permission denied
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.143.6_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

lsattr -R /lib/firmware

If I put in that command it pulls up thousands of files, I can't re-post that much material.

Comment: is the rootfs mounted read-only?  e.g. a read or write error while the rootfs is mounted with `errors=remount-ro` will cause the rootfs to be remounted RO.

Comment: What system is this run on?

Comment: Ubuntu is the OS

Comment: Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: If you run apt-get as root (sudo) and then you get Permission denied then that firmware files are protected, most likely with `chattr +i`. Readonly FS would return EROFS instead of EPERM. Brian Turner, please edit your post and include output of `lsattr -R /lib/firmware`, `lsattr -d /lib/firmware`

Comment: lsattr -R /lib/firmware Comes back with thousands of files, should I search for a certain directory and post?

Comment: OK post it to pastebin.com then

Comment: My user name on pastebin.com http://pastebin.com/fjQh95qB